# Do I need to insulate the walls in this attic cavity?

Tags: insulation, ceiling, attic

I have vaulted ceilings in the kitchen and dining room. The walls in the attic for that cavity are not insulated but the roof (rafters) are. I have added some insulation to the floor (ceiling above kitchen island). Do I also need to insulate the walls or would it be sufficient to close the entrance to that cavity in the attic with an R49 fiberglass insulation bats?
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If so, would it be faced isolation? Faced to drywall with the moisture barrier or barrier away from the drywall? The wall joists are 5 3/8 deep

Comment: You usually want insulation between living space and outside.  Depending on attic use, it is usually considered outside of the living space, so you insulate the attic floor only and ventilate the rest of the attic to the outside.  Vapour barrier goes on the heated/living side.

Comment: I understand that. But if look closely in my pictures, those walls in the attic are actually the sidewalls in my kitchen, so part of the living space right?

Comment: Normally attic ceilings/roofs are *not* insulated, and outside air is allowed to circulate through the attic. Without that it will develop dampness and mold, and the shingles can overheat, shortening their life.

Comment: @Matt your first comment is great fodder for a new question once you've got this one answered.

Comment: @RayButterworth I understand about the ceiling/roof in the attic - no insulation there.